# React Native Navigation Drawer with Hamburger button

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to create a drawer menu with [React Native Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation.html). By default the drawer seems to work only by swiping. I've also tried triggering the drawer with a button. It was all good, but the problem is that I'd like the button (with a hamburger icon) to slide along with the drawer when it is closing/opening. Here are a couple of sketches of what I'd like to see:
[image][image]

I tried searching for information but nothing useful came up. The closest I got was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007686/add-hamburger-button-to-react-native-navigation), but in this case the button triggers a new screen to open, not a drawer menu to slide in.

Is this even possible to do, since I couldn't even find anything in the [API docs for the DrawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator.html)? If so, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to put you btn inside the Drawer content? I believe it's shoild be something like `<TouchebleItem style={{position: 'absolute', right: -IMAGE_WIDTH}} />`, but it's just a concept.